# Very obvious Late Answer Review Audit

Tags: discussion

I got this audit today in the Late Answer review queue: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/8758456

It immediately screamed "AUDIT!!!!" at me, because the answerer has 1370 reputation, and upon inspection his account is over 3 years old. On the review page it states for the Late Answer queue: **Review late answers from new users** 
The audit initially stated that the question was answered 15 minutes ago, now it states 7 days ago. It's still a late answer, but it's not a new user.

It took only one other click on the question to discover the answer wasn't there anymore. Usually I would skip a c++ question, but as this was so obvious I decided to flag it. This case might not be suitable for an audit, and it makes me wonder how it even ended up as an audit for this queue.

Comment: Audits aren't supposed to be tricky; they're designed to be obvious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Congratulations - you passed!

Serious, audits are supposed to check that you are paying attention. They are *meant* to be obvious to anyone who's not just robo-reviewing.

Comment: Sure, I can see that, but isn't there such a thing as too obvious? I can't imagine anyone, not even robo-reviewers failing this one, and if that's the intended level of auditing it's not going to matter if there's auditing or not.

Comment: @Stephen - you'd be surprised at what robo-reviewers let through. You might think it's obvious, I might think it's obvious, but there are some people who really don't have a clue.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. I can accept that.

Comment: @Stephen some robo-reviewers never move from "approve" or "looks ok", just blindly clinking....